# Using standalone to combine multiple .tex into a single file

Tags: input, include, standalone

I have a number of latex files `section1.tex`, `section2.tex`, etc.  Each of them should be able to be compiled individually to give a normal LaTeX document.   I would like to write a file `master.tex` that will `\include` or `\input` these files and combine them into a single document.

Note that I do not want to edit the `section1.tex` file.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I have heard that the `standalone` package can do this, but I am having trouble getting the desired behavior.

My attempted `master.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\title{My Book}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\include{Section1.tex}
\end{document}
```

My attempted `Section1.tex` file

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{class=article,crop=false}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1}
Contents of Chapter 1.
\end{document}
```

The main problems I am having are

1. There are errors when compiling `Section1.tex` .  It states that this file might be missing an \item .  There are also an error about needing to insert a `}` and then later an error that there are too many `}'`s
2. The `\section{Chapter 1}` line is being cropped and placed as a second page.  The "Contents of Chapter 1" are placed at the top of a full page, with no top margin.
3. None of the text from `Section1.tex` seems to be included in `master.tex`.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: it's probably possible but it's always going to be fragile and introduce weird package dependencies on packages that work doing this, why not just do the _much_ simpler thing of just having the section bodies in files that you input (or include) and then to produce individual sections use `\includeonly` or have a small document with just a preamble and \input the section you want?

Comment: Don't use the standalone-class for section1 but also article.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had a project with hundreds of files which all could be compiled indidually but also input in larger master files. It work flawlessly and was very useful, as the single files had to be edited by various peoples on sharelatex. One naturally has to use the same preamble everywhere and understand what it does to labels.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The documentation for `standalone` states that the included files should have document class `standalone`.  I have the same errors and issues if I use `\documentclass[article]{standalone}` .

Comment: @UlrikeFischer as I say I know it can work, but I think (from what I see on questions here, not particularly this one) that it's over-used and people overlook the simpler (and often more robust) approaches to obtain the same thing,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this master:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\title{My Book}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\input{Section1.tex}
\end{document}
```

and this Section1

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1}
Contents of Chapter 1.
\end{document}
```

If your files are in different folders relative pathes can be wrong. In this case you can use for example the `import` package.

Comment: Thanks!  This works perfectly.  I suppose I misunderstood the documentation.  Also your use of the`\input` command works where the `\include` command I was using didn't.

Comment: A problem with this approach:
If the `section1.tex` file is in a folder `sections` and I use `\input{diagram}` in it (relative path to the file `diagram.tex` also in the `sections` folder) then when compiling the master file I get an error `File diagram.tex not found`.

Comment: @SilvanEgger I know but that wasn't the question here. You can find a number of question about relative pathes, search for `import` and  `subfiles`.

Comment: True. It's just that I used your answer and immediately faced the issue with the relative file path in `section1.tex`. Therefore at least a note like "don't use this approach when working with relative file paths in `section1.tex`" would have been helpful.